# EntityFramework relations giving incorrect results - WebAPI does not accept {id}

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am building a WebAPI and I have populated my Database with 5 different Organizations, each organization has 3 different Contacts, each Contact has 3 phone numbers with EntityFramework.
But somehow it behaves in a weird way:

- I get a complete list of Contacts and organizations
- I get just a contact under an organization (GET -> api/organizations)
- I get  just one phone under a contact (GET -> api/contacts)
- It does not accept parameter in the api routes such as: api/contacts/{id} or api/organizations{id}. It returns 404 code.

My questions:

**1- Are the relation between models is wrong built  and therefore I get just one sub-element instead the whole list?**

**2- Why does my routes do not accept parameters {id}?**

These are my models:

```
**Organization:**
public class Organization    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
        public string organizationName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }

**Contact:**
public class Contact    {
        public Contact() { }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

        // Foreign Key for Organizations
        public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }

        //Related Organization entity
        [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
        public Organization OrganizationData { get; set; }
    }

**Phones:**
public class Phone    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string customName { get; set; }
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }

        // Foreign Key for Contacts
        public Guid ContactId { get; set; }

        //Related Contact entity
        [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
        public Contact ContactData { get; set; }
    }
```

These are my controllers:

```
**OrganizationsController:**
    [Route("api/organizations")]
    public class OrganizationsController : Controller
    {
            [HttpGet ("")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
                var results = _repository.GetAllOrganizations();
                return Ok(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Organization>>(results));   
        }

 [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult Get(Guid Id)
        {
                var organization = _repository.GetOrganizationById(Id);
                return Ok(organization);
        }
    }

**ContactsController**
[Route("api/organization/{id}/contacts")]
    public class ContactsController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult Get(Guid Id)
        {
                var organization = _repository.GetOrganizationById(Id);
                return Ok(organization.Contacts.ToList());
        }
        }
    }

**AllContactsController**
[Route("api/contacts")]
        public class AllController : Controller
        {
        [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
                var results = _repository.GetAllContacts();
                return Ok(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Contact>>(results));
        }

        [HttpGet("/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(Guid Id)
        {
                var contact = _repository.GetContactById(Id);
                return Ok(contact);
        }
```

**EDIT: adding the repository:**

```
  public class ContactManagementRepository : IContactManagementRepository
    {
        private ContactManagementContext _context;
        private ILogger<ContactManagementRepository> _logger;

        public ContactManagementRepository(ContactManagementContext context, ILogger<ContactManagementRepository> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Organization> GetAllOrganizations()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Getting All Organizations from the Database");
            return _context.Organizations.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllContacts()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Getting All Contacts from the Database");
            return _context.Contacts.ToList();
        }

        public void AddOrganization(Organization organization)
        {
            _context.Add(organization);
        }

        public void AddContact(Guid id, Contact newContact)
        {
            var organization = GetOrganizationById(id);
            if(organization != null)
            {
                organization.Contacts.Add(newContact);
                _context.Contacts.Add(newContact);
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            return (await _context.SaveChangesAsync()) > 0;
        }

        public Organization GetOrganizationById(Guid Id)
        {
            return _context.Organizations
                .Include(c => c.Contacts)
                .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public Contact GetContactById(Guid Id)
        {
            return _context.Contacts
                .Include(c => c.Addresses)
                .Include(c => c.Bankdatas)
                .Include(c => c.Phones)
                .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public void DeleteContact(Guid id)
        {
            var contact = GetContactById(id);
            if (contact != null)
            {
                _context.Contacts.Remove(contact);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Repositories look good for me too. Can you more specify your question? What is exactly you sent and what is returned?

Comment: I get the list of all contacts and all organizations, but when I try to get the details from one organization (with its 3 Contacts) I just get ONE contact. the same is for Contacts where I just get ONE phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try for OrganizationsController

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(Guid Id)
{
        var organization = _repository.GetOrganizationById(Id);
        return Ok(organization);
}
```

and try for AllController

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(Guid Id)
{
        var contact = _repository.GetContactById(Id);
        return Ok(contact);
}
```

Your models look good for me. Can you show your repositories?

Comment: Sure, I added the repository